# Why is Django migrate command not creating tables in database for specific app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-tenants

I've an app named Attendance and it contains the following migrations applied in [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) db.

```
attendance
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_delete_leave
 [X] 0003_alter_holiday_options_alter_shift_options
 [X] 0004_delete_holiday_alter_shift_holidays
 [X] 0005_delete_shift
 [X] 0006_initial
 [X] 0007_alter_leave_options
 [X] 0008_alter_leave_comment_alter_leave_is_regularized
 [X] 0009_attendance
 [X] 0010_alter_attendance_options_attendance_created_at_and_more
 [X] 0011_attendance_status
 [X] 0012_attendance_is_regularized
 [X] 0013_alter_attendance_is_regularized
 [X] 0014_remove_attendance_date_attendance_start_date_and_more
 [X] 0015_attendance_end_date
 [X] 0016_alter_attendance_end_date
 [X] 0017_alter_attendance_end_date_and_more
 [X] 0018_leavetype_remove_leave_half_day_and_more
 [X] 0019_leave_leave_type
```

when I run `python manage.py migrate` with or without app label it does not create tables in db.

I've not set `managed=False` and tried to delete all migrations from `django_migrations` table but no luck.

One more point I forgot to add that I'm using [<kbd>django-tenants</kbd>](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

### Update

To debug the issue, I deleted my local database and kept migrations. Before migrating I ran migrate command with [**`--plan`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-plan) flag

```
python manage.py migrate --plan
```

Above command gives me this error

```
[standard:public]     Change Meta options on todo
[standard:public] todo_task.0004_todo_created_at_todo_updated_at

[standard:public]     Add field created_at to todo
[standard:public]     Add field updated_at to todo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "tenant_tenant" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "tenant_tenant"."schema_name" FROM "tenant_tenant" WH...

...
```

Comment: Look inside the migrations file and see if there is actually a request to create table.

Otherwise if you want a quick solution and you are not working on a deployement database, you can try to delete the schema of your base and recreate it. Delete all migration as well and retype makemigrations / migrates.

Comment: Hello @LorteauErwan, Thanks for your reply. There's a migration file inside the migrations folder. I've provided `python manage.py showmigrations` output in my question. I cannot delete migrations due to version control. I'm pushing my migrations on the server, so if I change migrations, it will create conflicts on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, according to the [**documentation**](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#configure-tenant-and-shared-applications). All the apps that we want to have their tables in the public schema, we've got to add them to **`SHARED_APPS`**.

So I added `attendance` and `task` apps in **`SHARED_APPS`**.

```py
SHARED_APPS = (
    'django_tenants',  # mandatory
    'attendance',
    'task',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # everything below here is optional
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

After this, I deleted my local database, created a new one, and ran the migrate command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It worked!

Thanks to all who tried to help me (:

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ~

You can reset to your last known migration by using this command

```
python manage.py migrate app_name migration_name
```

For example: `python manage.py migrate myapp 0001`

And then run your migrate command:

```
python manage.py migrate app_name
```

If this doesn't work, you can use the --fake flag to manipulate the current migration state.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myapp 0001
```

This is intended for more experienced users. Kindly see more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: Hi, I got solution and I already tried the commands you've provided but no luck.